# ASP.NET Core 5 + SQL Server Docker container: invalid compose project

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup a simple container on a raspberry pi4 using following [guide](https://samwalpole.com/how-to-run-aspnet-core-and-sql-server-from-docker).
For some reason I'm always bumping into the following error:

> [0mservice "my-api" has neither an image nor a build context specified: invalid compose project   docker-compose

As this is my first "real" docker container setup, I have no real idea of what to do now. I really looked up every single issue that I could find via google search (even tried it with bing, yeah that desperate). But I can't really find ant decent guide/answer.

I'll attach my docker files:
docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
web:
    build: .
    ports:
        - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
        - db
db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

DockerFile (API project)

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this 
Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0.302-buster-slim-amd64 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.302-buster-slim-amd64 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["my-api/my-api.csproj", "my-api/"]
RUN dotnet restore "my-api/my-api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/my-api"
RUN dotnet build "my-api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "my-api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my-api.dll"]

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
CMD /bin/bash ./entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
run_cmd="dotnet run --server.urls http://*:80"

until dotnet ef database update; do
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
exec $run_cmd
```

If someone can nudge me in the right direction, would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Indentation in your yaml file is important. Your services need to be indented under the `services:` line.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "Your_password123"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

Comment: The indent got wrecked while copying, so that's not it

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Studio (not code) for building this?

Visual Studio has an option "Place solution and project files in the same directory" Make sure that you check it before you become a pro with docker/docker-compose.

Visual studio tends to mess up the relative path of .csproj file when that option is unchecked and you add docker support (or Container orchestration support).

The `COPY ["my-api/my-api.csproj", "my-api/"]` is supposed to have relative path to `csproj` file.

Just a hunch.

Also, bing didn't help me either.